# French Characters

Tags: sql-server

I need to do an update with french characters in MS SQL SERVER, the problem is that I don't know where I can find a conversion list. For example I identified that this character `Ã‰` means `É`.

Where can I find the all corresponding list of symbols for each French character?
Thank you.

Comment: Ohlala! You probably have the encoding for the client set to W cp1252, where the DMBS assumes it has to be utf8.

Comment: is there any list of symbols that allow me to identify each character?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to update anything but only use the same,corresponding settings for client and server. Or is this freshly important data, imported with the wrong assumptions about the encoding? (NB: I am not a MS-expert, and don't know the exact tweaks for it)

Comment: I can't reload data again, so that's why I need to do a massive update finding this characters and replace them with the correct french character...

Comment: I'm French, if you supply a list of the special characters in context, I could help you along.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "É" is encoded as "Ã‰", that would be a very strange way to encode the character, using other special characters.

It seems rather the opposite:

I've noticed "É" is sometimes shown as ""Ã©". It's an encoding character error, due to character encoding not being appropriate for the language.

If you try to correct the righ French character from your error display characters, I don't know if such a list exist. You would first need to know what kind of error in the encoding character you make to find the list of the wrong displays.

So my suggested solution is here: Find the proper character encoding to solve this issue. Changing the encoding will normally fix the display.

For French characters, the right ones are **iso-8859-1** and **utf-8**. Once you have the right encoding, you can find a conversion list, translating your source code into displayed characters.

For instance, this list: http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/ISO-8859-1/list.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar in a `nvarchar` -> `varchar` conversion gone wrong.
Especially when concatenating and doing this:

```
e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName
```

Instead of doing:

```
e.FirstName + N' ' + e.LastName
```

Doing a `cast(nvarchar_field AS varchar(50))` - or the opposite, as required.
Bring everything to NVARCHAR, as this supports Unicode, which supports UTF-8.

Perhaps the actual table needs to be modified if the fields are varchar instead of nvarchar.